# QML application virtual keyboard behind fullscreen application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

I want to use Qt virtual keyboard in my QML application. I use Qt 5.9.4 and I am on Windows 7.

I tried the Qt example  called "basic", it works in "windowed" mode, but when I put the application window in full screen with

```
view.showFullScreen(); // instead of view.show() for windowed mode
```

the keyboard appears behind the application window and not above it, so it's not usable.

How to correct that?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, as I talk about Qt example, I thought, wrongly, that everyone had it.
Here is the code:

```
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view(QString("qrc:/%2").arg(MAIN_QML));

    if (view.status() == QQuickView::Error)
        return -1;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    view.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: what is `view`? please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In Linux the same does not happen, for me it is a bug.